# How create a function for multiple click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, click

initially i say that i'm newbie with jquery and js :D , i need to create a function in jquery to add a css rule after click event on a button, i have done it and it works:

```
   $(".resp-toogle").on("click",function() {
    $(".fit").css('top','200px');

});
```

in this case when there's a click action on .resp-toogle, there's a css rule added for fit css class. But i need that clicking again on .resp-toogle , would be a reset top margin for fit class.

I have checked documentation and tested something but i don't find solution.
I know i need study and test with jquery :).

Comment: So you want to do a double click event?

Comment: So what you want is the style to change if the user taps a set amount  of times?

Comment: not a double click, but a second click that reset condition changed after first click...there's not a taps limit, might be a different from odd and pair events i think
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want successive clicks on the element to enable/disable the `top` CSS positioning on the `.fit` element, you can use `toggleClass`.

Firstly, setup the class in your CSS:

```
.fit.top {
    top: 200px;
}
```

Then, use the `toggleClass()` function in your jQuery code:

```
$(".resp-toogle").on("click",function() {
    $(".fit").toggleClass('top');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kdbc61fp/)

Comment: Thank you Rory, it works correctly, i have only adjust class removing position tag that are broking my layout ;). Thank you so much.
Regards

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a sort of toggle button so try this:

add a css class

```
.themargin{
    top: 200px;
}
```

then toggle the class on each click

```
$(".resp-toogle").on("click",function() {
    $(".fit").toggleClass('themargin');
});
```

function docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: thank you too, it works in the same way Rory's answer, thank you ;)